# How to convert []byte to *bytes.Buffer

Tags: go, gob

I am trying to decode a gob output that I am sending through another fasthttp endpoint and receiving an error
Fasthttp endpoint(encode []string through gob) ----> Fasthttp endpoint( receive and decode)

```
buffer := &bytes.Buffer{}
buffer  = ctx.PostBody()
backToStringSlice := []string{}  
gob.NewDecoder(buffer).Decode(&backToStringSlice)
```

I am getting error: ctx.PostBody() (type []byte) as type *bytes.Buffer in assignment

how do I convert `[]byte` to `*bytes.Buffer`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `res := []byte{}; bytes.NewBuffer(res)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NewBuffer` will do what you want

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
        foo:=[]byte{65,66,67}
        z:=bytes.NewBuffer(foo)
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", foo, z)
}
```

Comment: wow...i feel ashamed i had to google this, so simple, thank you